# Update Android Studio's JDK

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I just updated Android Studio to the last version (2.2) (on windows) and now I'm getting the message:

> Error:
>
> Please use JDK 8 or newer.
>
> Download JDK 8 Select a JDK from the File System

I've downloaded and installed the jdk 1.8. Then, I change the settings:

Project properties (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S ) -> SDK Location -> Update the JDK with the new location -> Press button OK

But, nothing has changed. I'm still getting the same error and the settings doesn't change. I also tried executing Android Studio as admin.

Is this a bug? Do you know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that either `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK`, `JDK_HOME` or `JAVA_HOME` environment variable exists and points to valid JDK installation. Perhaps on your setup it still points to Java 7

Comment: It does'n seem to work. I did it, also I remove java 7. But Android Studio doesn't want to change. I removed the file '.AndroidStudioPreview2.2\config\options\jdk.table.xml' and the IDE set the setting's variable to 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre'

Answer (score 0):

You could try to uninstall jdk7. Or try and run the android studio setup wizard, where you will be prompted to enter the jdk version or press detect. It will then detect your latest version.